# Experiences with SEDA and C#?

Tags: multithreading, events, c#-3.0

I'm thinking about SEDA. We design at the moment an application (which is running on a server as a service) which must be multithreaded and message / event based.

The SEDA idea is very intresting and should match. But I cannot find articles etc. writing about experiences made with it.

My question(s) now is(are):

- Do you use ActiveMQ, MSMQ to implement the queues or do you have a self written class which acts as queue? We have written once a thread-safe FIFO Queue class which is very helpful in a multithreaded environment.
- Fit's the threadpool class of .NET for this or did you implement an own Threadpool / sheduler ?

Are there any traps / good practices?

Comment: Staged Event-Driven Architecture
see: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/proj/seda/

Comment: Anybody tried something in this area in recent years? Is the idea of SEDA architectures for Http server worth exploring or it proved rather dead end? Thanks, Michał

Comment: what i can recommend is to read the following blog post: http://matt-welsh.blogspot.ch/2010/07/retrospective-on-seda.html. Matt Welsh is the one who wrote his PhD on this.

Comment: @TomTom, that link is invalidated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that nobody has ever done somthing on this topic.

So we decided to implement our own (thread-safe) messaging infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for the update, would you add some details on your implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You should see this blog post I did found. I am currently working on this subject.

http://surana.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/seda-on-net/